# Pandas create a new df based on column in current df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to create a new df with a column based on couple of formula. I could create multiple df with group and merge. But is there an efficient way for achieve?

df_1 is as below,

```
  df_1 = pd.DataFrame([['A', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','Customer Backhaul','34,848','$-51,100'],
              ['A', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','FOB','75,357','$12,407,112'],
              ['A', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','Price','75,357','$12,407,112'],
              ['A', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','Vendor Freight - Delivered','40,511','$65,470'],
              ['B', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','Customer Backhaul','197,904','$-157,487'],
              ['B', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','FOB','931,866','$50,059,515'],
              ['B', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','Price','931,866','$62,333,500'],
              ['B', '1/1/2021','SKU_1','Vendor Freight - Delivered','740,355','$1,220,927']], 
              columns=['Group', 'Month','ID','Cost Type','Volume','Order Cost'])
```

Formulae for 'Value' column,

- Freight = Absolute value of (Customer Backhaul) + Vendor Delivered
- FOB = FOB
- Price = Price - Backhaul
- Volume = Volume of FOB

Out[df_2]

```
   Group   Month     ID      Cost Type   Volume    Cost
0   A   1/1/2021    SKU_1   Freight     75,357  $116,570
1   A   1/1/2021    SKU_1   FOB         75,357  $12,407,112
2   A   1/1/2021    SKU_1   Price       75,357  $12,434,063
3   B   1/1/2021    SKU_1   Freight     931,866 $1,378,414
4   B   1/1/2021    SKU_1   FOB         931,866 $50,059,515
5   B   1/1/2021    SKU_1   Price       931,866 $62,490,988
```

Comment: Just to be completely sure - you do not *need* the column `Formulae` in the dataframe, right? It is just for us to understand how the calculations are done?

Comment: just an explanation of the calculation (of column 'value'). sorry for confusion

Answer (score 4):

We can apply those formulae with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

- either return a `Volume`/`Cost` DataFrame per group
- or return a Series of `Cost` tuples and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) them

---

#### DataFrame option

1. First convert the number strings into actual numbers (or if you're loading data with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), use the `thousands` param):

   ```
   df_1['Volume'] = df_1['Volume'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
   df_1['Order Cost'] = df_1['Order Cost'].str.replace(r'[$,]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
   ```
2. Given a `Group`/`Month`/`ID` group, return its `Volume` and `Cost` as a dataframe:

   ```
   def formulae_df(g):
       # set index to Cost Type for simpler indexing
       g = g.set_index('Cost Type')

       # initialize empty result df
       df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Volume', 'Cost'], index=['Freight', 'FOB', 'Price']).rename_axis('Cost Type')

       # fill result df with forumlae
       df['Volume'] = g.loc['FOB', 'Volume']
       df.loc['Freight', 'Cost'] = abs(g.loc['Customer Backhaul', 'Order Cost']) + g.loc['Vendor Freight - Delivered', 'Order Cost']
       df.loc['FOB', 'Cost'] = g.loc['FOB', 'Order Cost']
       df.loc['Price', 'Cost'] = g.loc['Price', 'Order Cost'] - g.loc['Customer Backhaul', 'Order Cost']
       return df
   ```
3. Then apply `formulae_df` with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

   ```
   df_2 = df_1.groupby(['Group', 'Month', 'ID']).apply(formulae_df).reset_index()

   #   Group     Month     ID  Cost Type  Volume      Cost
   # 0     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1    Freight   75357    116570
   # 1     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1        FOB   75357  12407112
   # 2     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1      Price   75357  12458212
   # 3     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1    Freight  931866   1378414
   # 4     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1        FOB  931866  50059515
   # 5     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1      Price  931866  62490987
   ```

---

#### Series option with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Since each group has one `Volume` vs multiple `Cost`, we can generate `Cost` as a list/tuple and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) them:

1. The first step is still to convert the number strings into actual numbers:

   ```
   df_1['Volume'] = df_1['Volume'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
   df_1['Order Cost'] = df_1['Order Cost'].str.replace(r'[$,]', '', regex=True).astype(int)
   ```
2. Given a `Group`/`Month`/`ID` group, compute its `Volume` (value) and `Cost` (tuple):

   ```
   def formulae_series(g):
       # set index for easy loc access
       g = g.set_index('Cost Type')

       # compute formulae
       volume = g.loc['FOB', 'Volume']
       costs = {
           'Freight': abs(g.loc['Customer Backhaul', 'Order Cost']) + g.loc['Vendor Freight - Delivered', 'Order Cost'],
           'FOB': g.loc['FOB', 'Order Cost'],
           'Price': g.loc['Price', 'Order Cost'] - g.loc['Customer Backhaul', 'Order Cost'],
       }

       # return volume as a value and costs as tuples
       return pd.Series({'Cost Type': costs.keys(), 'Volume': volume, 'Cost': costs.values()})
   ```
3. When we apply `formulae_series` with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), note how the `Cost*` columns contain tuples:

   ```
   df_2 = df_1.groupby(['Group', 'Month', 'ID']).apply(formulae_series)

   #                                   Cost Type  Volume                           Cost
   # Group Month    ID
   # A     1/1/2021 SKU_1  (Freight, FOB, Price)   75357   (116570, 12407112, 12458212)
   # B     1/1/2021 SKU_1  (Freight, FOB, Price)  931866  (1378414, 50059515, 62490987)
   ```
4. So now [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) those tuples into rows:

   ```
   df_2 = df_2.explode(['Cost Type', 'Cost']).reset_index()

   #   Group     Month     ID  Cost Type  Volume      Cost
   # 0     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1    Freight   75357    116570
   # 1     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1        FOB   75357  12407112
   # 2     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1      Price   75357  12458212
   # 3     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1    Freight  931866   1378414
   # 4     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1        FOB  931866  50059515
   # 5     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1      Price  931866  62490987
   ```

---

#### Full code

Here are the steps recombined (including an optional conversion back to commas/dollars):

```
## load df_1
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([['A','1/1/2021','SKU_1','Customer Backhaul','34,848','$-51,100'],['A','1/1/2021','SKU_1','FOB','75,357','$12,407,112'],['A','1/1/2021','SKU_1','Price','75,357','$12,407,112'],['A','1/1/2021','SKU_1','Vendor Freight - Delivered','40,511','$65,470'],['B','1/1/2021','SKU_1','Customer Backhaul','197,904','$-157,487'],['B','1/1/2021','SKU_1','FOB','931,866','$50,059,515'],['B','1/1/2021','SKU_1','Price','931,866','$62,333,500'],['B','1/1/2021','SKU_1','Vendor Freight - Delivered','740,355','$1,220,927']],columns=['Group','Month','ID','Cost Type','Volume','Order Cost'])

## convert to numerics
df_1['Volume'] = df_1['Volume'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
df_1['Order Cost'] = df_1['Order Cost'].str.replace(r'[$,]', '', regex=True).astype(int)

## dataframe option
df_2 = df_1.groupby(['Group', 'Month', 'ID']).apply(formulae_df).reset_index()

## or apply formulae and explode costs
# df_2 = (df_1.groupby(['Group', 'Month', 'ID'])
#             .apply(formulae_series)
#             .explode(['Cost Type', 'Cost'])
#             .reset_index())

## optional: revert to comma/dollar strings
df_2['Volume'] = df_2['Volume'].map('{:,}'.format)
df_2['Cost'] = df_2['Cost'].map('${:,}'.format)
```

Output:

```
  Group     Month     ID  Cost Type   Volume         Cost
0     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1    Freight   75,357     $116,570
1     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1        FOB   75,357  $12,407,112
2     A  1/1/2021  SKU_1      Price   75,357  $12,458,212
3     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1    Freight  931,866   $1,378,414
4     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1        FOB  931,866  $50,059,515
5     B  1/1/2021  SKU_1      Price  931,866  $62,490,987
```

Answer (score 2):

I find it a bit difficult to understand when it is a calculation, and when you just want to create a text with the calculation, where the numbers come from etc.

I have provided an example below after my understanding of the issue (feel free to comment if I've misunderstood):

You could loop over each row, and then do the calculations for the value (and use the `replace` function for the Formulae)

```py
replace_dict = {"Freight":"ABS(Backhaul)+Vendor Delivered", "Price":"Price - Backhaul",...,}
df["Definition or Formulae"] = df["Cost Type"].replace(replace_dict) #Replace "Freight with "ABS(Backhaul)+Vendor" etc in a new column called "Definition and Formulae


#Do some calculations with the values in each row
def get_value(row):
   cost_type = row["Cost Type"]
   if cost_type == "Freight":
        return row["Backhaul"].abs()+ row["Vendor Delivered"]
   if cost_type== "Price":
        return row["Price"] - row["Backhaul"]
   .
   .
   return row["Value"]  # If nothing special to do, just return the value
df["Value"] = df.apply(get_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: i don't need a comment to be printed. but, i need to perform some calculation in 'Value' column as per provided formula

Comment: updated the question with appropriate expectations.. i hope this is clarifies